# Show that there exists function $f:[0.1] \to \mathbb{R}$ such that it has no derivative in no point of a dense subset of $[0,1]$.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, convex-analysis

To do that I have created a numbering of of rational expressions over $[0,1]$ in the form of
\begin{align*}
\{q_{k} | k \in \mathbb{N} \}
\end{align*}
with function
\begin{align*}
g(t) = \sum_{k: q_{k} \leq t} \dfrac{1}{2^k}.
\end{align*}
It's easy to show that $g$ is increasing. I am supposed to use that fact to define an appropriate function $f$ to finish up, but I have no idea what.

Comment: Just define a 2-valued function that has no derivative anywhere.

Comment: Do you need a continuous function?

Comment: Your idea seems to be this: defeat differentiability by making the function discontinuous on a dense set.  Heck, make it discontinous everywhere.  As it stands, your problem is a bit silly.  Are you sure there were not more assumptions?  Perhaps $f$ is supposed to be monotone?  Or continuous? Or Lipschitz? Or ...?

Comment: @Michael any ideas? I do not get you.

Comment: @B.S.Thomson If you read what I wrote, I already set a numbering system for $[0,1]$ in the type of $g$. Knowing that it's increasing, we only need a function $f$ to do that. Whether $f$ is monotonous, continuous, Lipschitz or anything I think it is not of great importance.

Comment: Ok.  The function you have defined $g(t)$ is monotonic increasing and is discontinuous precisely at each rational number in $[0,1]$.  Therefore it is not differentiable at any rational number.  A simpler example is to define $f(x)=0$ for $x$ rational and $f(x)=1$ otherwise.  Then $f$ is discontinuous everywhere and hence not differentiable anywhere.  That is what @Michael had in mind.

Comment: @B.S.Thomson Many thanks, that's what I had in mind. I will double check it when I get home. If you want, write it as an official answer so that I can green you.

Comment: How is this related to convex analysis?

Comment: @Martin exercise in a book on convex analysis (greek authorship) that I am skimming through these days.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*More than you might care to know about this function:*

The standard example of a monotonic function which is discontinuous precisely at the rationals is given by
$$f_φ(x)=∑_{φ(n)<x} \frac{1}{2^n}, \tag{1}$$
where $φ$ is a bijection from $\mathbb N$ onto $\mathbb Q$.

The poster (correctly) offered this function (essentially) as an example of an increasing function with a dense set of points of discontinuity.  In fact the set of discontinuities is exactly the rationals.  Clearly, too, the function $f_φ$ fails to have a derivative at each rational (simply because a derivative cannot exist at a point of discontinuity).

*Is there more that can be said?  Never ask a mathematician that since there is always more.*

1. This function has discontinuities at each rational and is continuous at each irrational.  Can this be reversed?  Is there a function continuous at each rational and discontinuous at each irrational? This is not possible for monotonic functions: every monotonic  function has at most countably many discontinuities.  More surprising (and more difficult to prove): there is no function, monotonic or not, that is continuous at each rational number and discontinuous at each irrational number.
2. Functions like this are called **saltus functions** [Latin: *saltus*=jump, leap].  This function does all of its growing on the countable set of rationals where it has a jump up--it does no growing on the irrationals.  Important class of functions of which (1) is your standard interesting example.  Every monotonic function can be expressed as a sum of a continuous monotonic function and a monotonic saltus function.  Worth studying.
3. Another feature of this function is that it is continuous on the right at every point and it has a limit on the left at every  point.  At a countable set (here of  rational points) *only* do  the left and right limit differ.  Such functions are called   **càdlàg functions** (French: "continue à droite, limite à gauche").  Again an important class of functions with this one as a good illustration.  Important in stochastic processes, Fourier series, etc.
4. A reasonable question in light of this posted question:  This function is discontinuous at the rationals so it has no derivative at any rational point.  But it is continuous at the irrationals.  *So is it differentiable at the irrationals?* The answer is tricky.  It must be differentiable at many irrational numbers because it is a monotonic function.  On the other hand (more delicate) there are lots of irrational points where it does not have a derivative.  See #5, #6, #7 for these, taken from reference [1].
5. In every nontrivial interval there exists a nowhere dense null set $Z$ of irrational numbers such that every $f_φ$ has uncountably many points of nondifferentiability in $Z$. (See [1].)
6. If a one-sided derivative of an $f_φ$ exists at a point, then it is either infinite or it vanishes. (See [1].)
7. For every countable set $C$ there exists an $f_φ$ whose derivative exists (and vanishes) at every point of the set $C$.  (See [1].)

---

**REFERENCE:**

[1]  Kuba, Gerald. *On the differentiability of certain saltus functions*.
Colloq. Math. 125 (2011), no. 1, 15–30.